# I bought a stock twice and my app shows my the average price of my holdings

Tags: stocks

The first buy was in higher price, some days ago. Second buy is at lower price today, but the platform im using shows me that now I have "average price" of that stock, which is lower today because I bought more at lower price. So if I make small gains in couple days and want to sell for profit, I can't because I see the average price, not the actual price I bought today. So If the stock rise abit, I can't sell for profit because my price is higher. Is that normal or a bug? Never bought the same stock twice.

Comment: What app? Where are you? Rules differ from country to country, interfaces change from provider to provider...

Comment: So does mine, and honestly that's all the information I need...

Answer (score 1):

If your broker provides daily statements, check them for purchase details.  If not, check the Positions page.  If neither are available on your App, access the broker via a computer.  If you don't have a computer, call the broker and in the future, write down purchase prices.

Answer (score 0):

More details are always there you just have to know how to find them. Any broker will allow you to look at tax lots and allow you to configure the order in which you sell. Sound like you are looking at a dashboard that gives some sort of money-weighted return or other calculated value.

If you want specifics for your app then you need to contact their support or ask their community.

Comment: So you are saying that, if for example I buy a stock for 200, then some time later for 150. then hold and the stock rise to 170, I can sell only the 150 position right? What im looking at is the information when trying to sell, like I don't have the option to choose which position

Comment: You can sell either position at any time. However, if you want to sell the lot purchased at $150, you'll have to be able to designate that lot on your App or computer.

Comment: @Dor this really depends on how capital gains are calculated. For some transactions or in some countries - prices are in fact averaged and gain is calculated on the average purchase price. In this case, knowing what was the purchase price of which lot is unnecessary and brokers may not even track it. It's impossible to answer your question without knowing where you are.

Comment: I've read some and in my country the selling works in FIFO method - first in first out. So I can't choose which position to sell. That makes sense? Why would it be like that

Comment: Yes. It makes as much sense as any other rule. In the US we can specify lots if we really want to muck around at that level of detail, but the default is usually FIFO unless we tell the broker we prefer LIFO. For my own bookkeeping, I just track number of shares, average purchase price, and current market price, tell the broker to use FIFO, and ignore the details until I have to copy the info from the brokerage statements to my income taxes.